# Make file Error on solaris9 machine: Dont know how to make target

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

```
#compile time flags
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror
CC=gcc
all:    prog-1-gcc prog-2-gcc prog-3-gcc prog-4-gcc prog-5-gcc prog-6-gcc \
        prog-7-gcc prog-8-gcc prog-9-gcc prog-10-gcc prog-11-gcc prog-12-gcc \        
        prog-13-gcc prog-14-gcc prog-15-gcc prog-16-gcc prog-17-gcc prog-18-gcc \        
        prog-19-gcc prog-20-gcc prog-21-gcc
all-gcc:    all
run:    run-1-gcc run-2-gcc run-3-gcc run-4-gcc run-5-gcc run-6-gcc \
        run-7-gcc run-8-gcc run-9-gcc run-10-gcc run-11-gcc \
        run-12-gcc run-13-gcc run-14-gcc run-15-gcc run-16-gcc \
        run-17-gcc run-18-gcc run-19-gcc run-20-gcc run-21-gcc
run-gcc:    run
prog-%-gcc: prog-%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o prog-$*.out
run-%-gcc:  prog-%.out
    -./prog-$*.out
make clean:
    rm -f all *.out
```

This makefile gives me this error on solaris9 machine when i type

```
bash-2.05$ make prog-9-gcc
make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `prog-9-gcc'
```

This happens with all rules including the make clean rule. I would appreciate anyone's input as i have been stuck with this bug for a few days now thanks!I should also probably mention this makefile runs 100% perfectly on a centos machine.

Question: What can i do to my make file or my input line on solaris to make this work when compiling and running my C Files.

Answered Below in the comments by Charlie Burns

Comment: Instead of "make prog-9-gcc:" try "make prog-9-gcc" ?

Comment: Im sorry that was a typo i am not inputing the ":"

Comment: Im confused as to why my post got 2 down votes. did i do something wrong? i thought i followed all the rules for posting, im sorry i am new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule tells make it can build `prog-9-gcc` from a file `prog-9.c`.  So, if make is giving that error it means that there's no file `proc-9.c` in your directory:

```
prog-%-gcc: prog-%.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) prog-$*.c -o prog-$*.out
```

The other problem with this rule is that it tells make it will build a file `prog-%-gcc` (for some value of `%`) but it's lying.  It actually builds a totally different file, `prog-%.out`.  Because of this, make will rebuild all the targets every time you run make.  This rule should read:

```
prog-%-gcc: prog-%.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Really you should set `CC = gcc` and use `$(CC)` in the rule.

Comment: here is a screen shot of the makefile working fine on a centos machine.
http://i.imgur.com/yyy826a.png
i really appreciate your help and any feedback you have to offer. I made the changes to my makefile like you said and it still gives me the fatal error! The following screen shot is the error in action and as you can see the prog-9.c file is in the directory!

http://i.imgur.com/woiHMzh.png

Comment: Well, there's something obviously not the same.  Run `ls -l prog-9.c` (type it out exactly like that).  Maybe the one on Solaris has some invisible whitespace.  Or the permissions are wrong.  If that seems ok, then run `make -d proc-9-gcc` and look at the debug output and see why make decides it can't build the target.  There will be a lot of output but you should be able to follow it.  Finally, check the version of GNU make on your Solaris system (run `make --version`).  Maybe it's a very old version with some bugs that have since been fixed.

Comment: Your going to have to forgive me as i am pretty new to this stuff, here is what i get after typing out the lines you suggested:

http://i.imgur.com/eqZuQSN.png

Comment: It looks like your make is not gmake and does not support some syntax. Try using "gmake" instead of "make" and see if makes any difference.

Comment: This has worked! thank you so much for assistance if i knew how to give you rep i would.